# How to implement/merge C# interface into a simple C++ program using Visual Studio Express 2013

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, interface

I'm just a rookie in programming. Currently in my semester learning C++. So basically I've basic knowledge of C++. I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 for my basic codings. 
I've got an assignment about getting orders, display them, count total price and print a receipt. This time lecturer asked us to try to use an interface, either .NET or C#. I've watched some videos on how to use C# to create interfaces but what has been going through my brain is how do i use my codes in C++ with the interfaces in C#?

Thanks a lot for any response !

Comment: The instructor said ".NET or C#", so that tells me perhaps C++/CLI is appropriate - C++/CLI has interfaces (e.g., public interface class IFoo).

Answer (score 1):

There is no interface in C++. You could code a class with pure virtual methods to achieve the same functionality:

**C#**

```
interface Foo {
  void Bar();
}
```

**C++**

```
class Foo {
public:
  virtual void Foo()=0;
}
```

Here is a [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function) for more info.

Comment: thanks for your response! Is that like a bridge between C++ and C#? 
I've created a C# Windows Forms Application. I've got the basic Form.
with codes 
namespace name
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
how do i continue from there?

Comment: `Form` is a base class, not an interface: its methods are defined (not just declared like in interface) and inherited into `Form1`. I'd recommend to download Visual Studio for C++, use the designer to design a simple form application and look into the generated code. It is very much like in C#, just the syntax is C++ (enriched by some extensions for managed applications, just ignore them for now).